# Не запускается jar-файл собранный maven

Tags: java, maven

Создал тестовое приложение:

```
package ru.main.MnvTest;

import javafx.application.Application;
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        System.out.println( "Hello World!" );
        Application.launch(StartWindow.class, args);
    }
}

package ru.main.MnvTest;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class StartWindow extends Application {
       @Override
       public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
             VBox vBoxStartWindow = new VBox(15.0);
             vBoxStartWindow.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);
             vBoxStartWindow.setPadding(new Insets(20.0));
             Button button1 = new Button("Кнопка 1");
             Button button2 = new Button("Кнопка 2");
             vBoxStartWindow.getChildren().addAll(button1, button2);
             Scene sceneStartWindow = new Scene(vBoxStartWindow, 1024.0, 768.0);
             primaryStage.setTitle("Главное окно");
             primaryStage.setScene(sceneStartWindow);
             primaryStage.show();
       }
}
```

Pom файл:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>ru.main</groupId>
  <artifactId>MnvTest</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>MnvTest</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Если создаю Jar-файл через IDE Eclipse, то все ок. А если через Maven, то jar-ник не запускается. Вот сборка Maven.
Запускаю через батник:

```
start C:\Developer\jdk-11.0.8.10-hotspot\bin\javaw.exe --module-path C:\Developer\JavaFX\11\lib --add-modules ALL-MODULE-PATH -jar %1
```

Что не так?

Comment: javaw.exe .... вы выполняете из командной строки или она у вас укзана в командном файле и вы его запускаете с параметром?

Comment: использую bat-файл

Comment: Получилось разобраться? Что-то похожеее у меня тоже было, но так и не нашел, почему.

Answer (score 1):

Вам надо указывать в maven точку входа (mainClass), примерно так:

```
<configuration>
            <archive>
                <manifest>
                    <mainClass>app.Main</mainClass>
                </manifest>
            </archive>
</configuration>
```